# MySQL new user PRIVILEGES not working

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

I created a user to only select/Read data from MySQL but I can still drop tables from database.
what is wrong in this SQL script.

```
create user 'test'@'%' Identified by 'test!';
grant SELECT ON * . * TO 'test'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Did you connect to your database as root before you ran those commands? What OS are you running on?

Comment: mysql is in linux and i am using mysql clinet to connect. Yes I created this user using root user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the database as root.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I also notice that the proper command should be

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'%';
```

Meanwhile yours is

```
grant SELECT ON * . * TO 'test'@'%';
```

That is, you got too many spaces (this could be the dealbreaker).

Then just use the test user

```
mysql -u test -p
```

And run an update query.

You should receive an error

```
command denied to user
```

You could also try to tell what exactly you're using:

```
GRANT SELECT ON databasename.viewname TO 'test'@'identifythehost';
```

Comment: still i can drop the tables :(

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `test` database is modifiable by everyone.
Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db IN('test', 'test\_%');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```